# A new xarray DataArray from output of yearly idxmin() of another xarray Dataset/DataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray

The xarray dataset I am working is of ERA-5 data, containing multiple years (1991-2020) daily data. I am trying to find out the first day of the year for all years when a certain threshold is crossed. I would like to save the resulted 30 DataArrays as a single DataArray or Dataset with a coordinate/dimension year containing the numerical values of the years.
So, the result would be similar to the result if I were calculating yearly mean, e.g.

```
dsxr.groupby('time.year').mean()
```

In dataset "dsxr" a variable "ends" contains value zero for no crossing the threshold, and other positive values indicates crossing the threshold value.

If I take the entire data (containing all years), the first Day of the Year (DoY) can be retrieved with idxmin() method on time dimension. So far, I have been trying to apply the same logic for smaller datasets with each containing 1 year's data. But, I am unable to save the (combined) results as a new DataArray/Dataset.

Below is the code I came up with so far. How to modify it, or make better, so that I get a new DataArray/DataSet containing yearly result of idxmin() along the dimention "year"?

```
for year in range(1991, 2021):
    yr = str(year)
    hwt_da = dsxr.ends.sel(time=slice(yr,yr))  # Gets yearly subset of original dataset, dsxr, for the variable "ends" 
    dT = hwt_da.indexes['time'].strftime('%j').astype(int)  # Formats cftime to DoY as integers
    hwt_da['time'] = dT   # Assigns DoY as time
    hh = hwt_da.where(hwt_da>0).idxmin(dim='time').assign_coords({'year': year})  # Gets first DoY (idxmin()) when the threshold is above 0 
    if year == '1991':
        da = hh.copy()  # copy the first year's result
    else:
        xr.concat([da, hh], dim='year')  # Concatenates the rest year's results
```

The result I get from the loop [image]

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake I made. I did not assign the concatenated arrays to the variable da. Here is the updated code that works. I also found that xr.nested_combine() method works well too.

```
if year == 1993:  # the year should be integer not string
    da = hh.copy()
else:
    da = xr.concat([da, hh], dim='year') # I was not storing the concatenated arrays in variable da
    # da = xr.combine_nested([da, hh], concat_dim='year') # this works too
```